# Getting ng build --prod error for angular-2-daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

2-daterangepicker** in my project in local it is working fine, when i run ng build --prod i am getting below error.
npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-daterangepicker

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'DaterangepickerModule in E:/projects/backoffice_yash/node_modules/angular-2-daterangepicker/index.js' imported by the module 'SharedModule in E:/projects/backoffice_yash/src/app/_shared/shared.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

any help ...

Comment: look at this links may be it can help you https://github.com/technikhil314/angular-2-daterangepicker/issues/33 , https://github.com/technikhil314/angular-2-daterangepicker/issues/33#issuecomment-433033030

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DaterangepickerModule` is compatible only with Angular 4 and 5. If you are using Angular 6+ it might not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Share your angular version as it is only compatible with Angular 4 & 5.